# Calculation maximum points at a particular radius

Tags: c#, google-maps, coordinates

I have a point on the map (Google Map),

and I want to get all the points within a certain radius,

Is there a way to know the maximum points of the specific radius?

(Calculation on C # code)

Comment: Get all of what points?  You have a list of locations and you want to know if you can tell which of those locations are within X radius of the center point?

Comment: I want to get the maximum coordinates on X Radius

Comment: You aren't being clear.  Theoretically the area, circumference, diameter, and radius of a circle each contain infinite points.

Comment: I found a site that answers my request, thanks anyway.

Comment: http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a site that answers my request:

http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates